# what type of input scanner do you use in name =input.?

Tags: java

if you are using integer you use `int age = input.nextInt();`

and if you are using strings you use `int name = input.nextLine();`

what do you use for **char**?

Comment: WHy not just look at the API specification on what is available? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

easiest way for non-multibyte encodings: Use `nextByte()`and cast it to a char.

Comment: thank you very much it has worked

Answer (score 1):

FOr ASCII-only:

```
char myChar = (char) input.nextByte();
```